# C++ What does a name after 'class myClass' specify?

Tags: c++, class, syntax

I know that in C++, classes inherit with the form of `class childClass : public parentClass`, and similar variants. However, I was looking through the SFML (a C++ game programming library) header files, and I found this:

```
namespace sf
 {
   ...
   class SFML_API Drawable
   {
   public :
    ...
```

I'm confused about what this means in terms of C++ syntax. A class name can't contain spaces, and there is no colon or any other symbol. What is the meaning of this syntax?

Comment: I'd guess that SFML_API is some sort of macro and Drawable is the actual class name. See http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6470.0

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers written in all caps like this are, by common convention, usually either **preprocessor macros** or **constants**.

Given this fact, if you search through the other headers, you may find a line like:

```
#define SFML_API __declspec(dllexport)
```

On my own installation of SFML 2.1, I find these lines in Config.hpp:

```
#define SFML_API_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
// ... later...
#define SFML_API_EXPORT __attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default")))
```

This `__declspec` keyword tells compilers on Windows that the declaration that follows is to be treated as an **exported symbol** in a shared library. Similarly, the `__visibility__` attribute tells GCC-compatible compilers that the symbol is to be visible outside the library. This makes it possible for an application to link to the dynamic/shared library and use its code.